# no such file to load -- .bundle/environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integrity

I installed integrity app these days. and found some issues.

I follow this.

> $ gem install bundler
>   $ git clone git://github.com/integrity/integrity
>   $ cd integrity
>   $ git checkout -b deploy v22
>   $ bundle install
>   $ bundle lock
>   $ rake db

at the end steps, I can't find and folders named ".bundle" in the integrity folder. 
and the .bundle/environment.rb too. 
so I was blocked there.

and btw, anybody can sent me a better way to install and config integrity app?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have a *too recent* version of bundler installed. Integrity v22 is not compatible with bundler > 0.9, but relies on functionality that was in removed in the subsequent version. In my case I installed bundler 0.9 before I ran bundle install:

```
gem install bundler --version=0.9
```

You might have to uninstall the newer bundler version, too.